# What's the meaning of "me choca" expression?

Tags: coloquialismos

- What's the meaning of the mexican expression "**me choca**"?
- Is it used in any other regions?

Examples:

> Me choca que cuando estoy dormido suene el teléfono y me despierte.
>
> Me choca tener que ir a misa todos los domingos.
>
> Me choca que siempre me des la contra.
>
> Tú me chocas.
>
> Eres una persona chocante.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up on the [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=chocar)? I think this is the meaning you were looking for: "Causar extrañeza o enfado." It would be like "It bothers me..."

Comment: @Alenanno That should be an answer.

Comment: "Me molesta mucho ...". Similar phrases: "Me jode ...", "Me revienta ..."

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for the site as the answer is very easily found in google and specifically in RAE. I'll make a meta question regarding this issue.

Comment: @Joze That's too bad because even though I knew the answer what I wanted was to make people participate by generating content. So I think is better to generate questions that might not be a great quality question than nothing at all. This is very important at this early stage and by being so strict in the quality of the questions the only thing that will happen is that users will stop participating because of the fear that the question that they want to ask might not be good enough for the site. Also as we can see by a Javi comment "chocar" in Spain means a totally differen thing than Mexico.

Comment: The regional difference of the meaning was something that I didn't know and is also a thing that RAE doesn't specify.

Comment: Yes of course I know what you mean, but the site is also not about volume of questions, but quality of knowledge found here. Why come here if the knowledge can be very easily found in an accredited site? Anyway I made the question in meta I just want a discussion about it, as the site is so young I feel it important to discuss. Here is the question we would gladly hear your opinion about it!!! :) [Question](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/167/are-general-definition-questions-allowed/168#168)

Comment: @Alfredo: For *chocante*, RAE *does* add the regional distinction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Chocar* literally means "to crash."  For example, it's used to describe an unexpected meeting between two automobiles.  Colloquially, it means to clash or annoy.  Someone acting obnoxious or confrontational is frequently described (at least in Argentina, where I learned the language) as *chocante*.  So:

> Me choca que cuando estoy dormido suene el teléfono y me despierte.

It annoys me when I'm sleeping and the phone rings and wakes me up.

> Me choca tener que ir a misa todos los domingos.

Having to go to Mass every Sunday bugs me.

> Me choca que siempre me des la contra.

I don't like how you always contradict me.

> Tú me chocas.

You bother me.

Comment: I forgot the existence of "chocante" so I added an example for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=chocar), among the other meanings, it has "causar extrañeza o enfado", which is the one related to your question.

I think in your cases it can be translated as follows:

> Me choca que cuando estoy dormido suene el teléfono y me despierte.
>
> ***It bothers me/it makes me angry/it annoys me** that when I'm sleeping, the phone rings and it wakes me up.*

I'm not sure about where it's more used, but [Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=chocar) states:

> (Col, Méx, Ven fam) (irritar, molestar) (+ me/te/le etc) to annoy, bug (colloq);

Comment: in Spain it is used too and is quite informal. It usually means something like "I was surprised by"

Comment: @Javi very different usage than Mexico. That would be for "extrañeza" definition that RAE points out.

Comment: I agree with @Javi. "chocar" is used as "to cause surprise" and "chocante" as "shocking" in Spain.

Comment: @MikMik My answer doesn't contrast that, considering the last quote. But thanks for the add!